# Схема редактирования записи

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две формы. В первой список клиентов, вторая форма для редактирования записи. После редактирования данные о клиенте обновляются в БД и на первой форме происходит обновление по данному клиенту. Вопрос заключается в том, как грамотно реализовать данную задачу? Именно передать с первой формы данные на вторую форму, а после редактирования передать обратно измененные данные? На данный момент передаю через свойства, но на сколько это правильно - не знаю. Пожалуйста, можете дать общую схему? дальше сам.

Comment: вам важно знать, изменился объект или нет?

Comment: а что за база данных? данные заполняются через DataGridView?

Comment: Грамотно передать данные можно только, через базу данных, которая служит единственным хранилищем всех изменений. Чтобы изменения на первой форме были видны после коррекции данных с помощью второй, вторая форма должна сделать UpDate() первой. (По ошибке я оформил эту реплику, как ответ и к ней уже успели написать комментарий :) на который я отвечу ниже.

Comment: Комментарий был следующим: "...Ох насоветуете. Зачем базе знать, что я нажал кнопку "Редактировать запись"? Пусть получает только отредактированный объект. – Ruslan Artamonov 4 мин. назад..." - уважаемый Руслан речь об изменении в БД, и поэтому не стоит плодить сущности и иметь "гемморой" с внесением в них синхронных изменений

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Я правильно понял, что вы советуете получать объект из БД по началу редактирования, сохранять его в БД, потом снова запрашивать из БД после редактирования?

Comment: @Ruslan Artamonov, да изменяемый объект должен быть один, а у объекта уже может быть много View (углов зрения). Это в идеале. На практике могут быть отступления от этого правила, главное не перейти грань, после которой система становится сложна для сопровождения.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Почему нельзя работать с этим одним объектом, не трогая при этом БД? Передаем второй форме этот объект и все.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов В вашем случае появляется одна лишняя зависимость Форма2-БД, которую можно избежать.

Comment: Спасибо всем, но что-то вопросов у меня больше стало.

Comment: @Ruslan Artamonov, Потому, что внеся изменения в какой-то "левый объект", и не сохранив их в БД, Вы рискуете их потерять, а сами изменения будут не видимы в других View, которые могут в других процессах и даже на других машинах.

Comment: Данные в БД сохраняются. Вопрос в том: тянуть из БД или передать на первую форму из второй?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Вносим изменения мы не в "левый объект", а в оригинальный. Потом его и сохраняем. После закрытия формы2.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Мнения разделились) Можно и так и так, как вам более правильным кажется. Если есть вероятность того, что после сохранения БД может еще как-то изменить данные, то конечно первое. Если нет - я бы выбрал второе. Только не создавайте копию объекта (если конечно вам не требуется откат через отмену)

Comment: Вероятность есть, но 0.00001%

Comment: @Ruslan Artamonov - случай из жизни. В немодальном окне, которое редактор, мы исправили данные, и после, не закрывая его, вернулись в прежнее окно, где что-то тоже изменили. И в этот момент у Вас отключают  электричество. Я думаю дальше тему Вы разовьете сами :)

Comment: Ruslan Artamonov можешь оформить свой ответ?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов То есть мы добавляем 3 операции с БД на случай отключения электричества? Ну если это продукт для работы с деньгами, может быть. А если программа учета носков - зачем?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код к первой форме предлагаю примерно такой:

```
//редактируемый объект
Data data;

EditorForm editor = new EditorForm();
//внедряем редактируемый объект в форму редактирования
editor.Data = data

//EditorForm при нажатии на кнопку OK делает валидацию и редактирует объект из полей
//Соответственно, если нажали OK - значит объект изменился.
//Обратно ничего передавать не надо
if (editor.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //сохраняем объект в БД
    //Например, для Entity Framework
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Из первой формы данные, обернув, скажем в объект/структуру, передать в конструкторе второй формы, а в классе второй формы выделить публичный метод, за который дернет первая форма после завершения редактирования.

что-нибудь вроде этого:

```
using (ВашаВтораяФорма f = new ВашаВтораяФорма(ВашОбъектСДанными))
{

    if (f.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    var ИзмененныеДанные = f.GetData();
    // действия с ними - обновление первой формы, запись в БД и т.д.
}
```

Comment: Либо получить объект через публичное свойство. А можно вообще не получать его, если мы передаем в конструкторе ссылку и форма 2 изменяет объект по ссылке.

Comment: А какой принцип отработки публичного метода? Не понимаю  значения "дернет".

Comment: "Дернет" - сохранит в БД и передаст на первую форму???